# Reference a Shared Sub Folder in an inbox

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm looking to modify my VBA code to reference a shared inbox that has a subfolder inside of it. The commented out code worked with my main inbox folder and a sub folder called test. I've tried to use the getSharedDefaultfolder method but the code currently does not detect an email being placed in the subfolder of my shared inbox. Does anyone have any thoughts or recommendations?

````
Public WithEvents objInbox As Outlook.Folder

Public WithEvents objInboxItems As Outlook.Items



Private Sub Application_Startup()
Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set shrdRecip = olNs.CreateRecipient(test@outlook.com)
Set Inbox = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(shrdRecip, olFolderInbox).Folders("test")

'Set objInbox = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("test")'

'Set objInboxItems = objInbox.Items'
Set objInboxItems = Inbox.Items


End Sub



Private Sub objInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem

Dim objForward As Outlook.MailItem

MsgBox Item.Subject




If TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then

Set objMail = Item





MsgBox objMail.UnRead

If (objMail.UnRead Or False) Then



Set objForward = objMail.Forward



With objForward

.Subject = "Custom Subject"

.HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Type body here. </BODY></HTML>" & objForward.HTMLBody

.Recipients.Add (usr@yahoo.com)

.Recipients.ResolveAll

.Send
MsgBox Item.Subject

End With

End If

End If

End Sub

Sub MyTEST()



End Sub```
````

Comment: Do you see the shared folder `test` in Outlook?

Comment: Yes, I am able to see the sub folder test with the shared mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the shared folder/store to your Outlook profile if you want to get events fired in VBA.

Also make sure an instance of the `Items` class was initialized correctly in the code to get the events fired.

I'd suggest calling the [Recipient.Resolve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.resolve) method before accessing the shared folder, it attempts to resolve a `Recipient` object against the Address Book.

Comment: I've got access to the shared folder now. I am able to drill down inside of it and view emails in the folders. Is there some sort of additional access I would need to run events?

Comment: Make sure the source folder is initialized correctly in the code.

Comment: You will find Resolve has no impact on email addresses. Try on any text that looks like an email address.

Comment: What impact do you expect? It returns true or false which indicates the fact that a corresponding entry is found in the address book.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `objInboxItems`  is not null? By default, `GetSharedDefaultFolder` only returns the folder but not its subfolders unless the shared mailbox is added to the profile as a delegate mailbox and and all its folders are synchronized by Outlook.